# Now() is Oct 31st. Carbon thinks next month is December. Can someone set me straight on why that is?

Tags: php-carbon

This is what I happen to be getting off my php command line at the moment.  Does anyone have any thoughts on why this is correct yet perhaps not intuitive?

```
>>> Carbon\Carbon::now()
=> Carbon\Carbon @1540947288 {#3407
 date: 2018-10-31 00:54:48.064619 UTC (+00:00),
}
>>> Carbon\Carbon::parse('next month')
=> Carbon\Carbon @1543625671 {#3379
 date: 2018-12-01 00:54:31.923687 UTC (+00:00),
}
>>> Carbon\Carbon::parse('last month')
=> Carbon\Carbon @1538357012 {#3298
 date: 2018-10-01 01:23:32.720005 UTC (+00:00),
}
```

Comment: Probably because a month from now is Nov 31st, but Nov only has 30 days, so the 31st rolls to Dec 1.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ya, valid point.  I've seen code behave that way - allowing me to draft a date like Nov 31 yet it returns a corrected Dec 1.

Comment: It's probably the problem Carcigenicate describes. However, I personally find it not intuitive that from Oct 31, the next month is December. I would prefer that the (obviously nonexistent) 31st of November was corrected to the actual last day of the month, i.e. Nov 30.

Comment: @MCEmperor I'm more fussed about the 'last month'.  lol

Comment: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/1491

Comment: @TarekAdam I didn't see that one. Yeah, that one is even more confusing than 'next month', but I think both issues have the same root: an invalid date (Nov 31 and Sep 31) being 'corrected' to the next valid date.